# Matplotlib: plot multiple graphs on the same plot when different functions in the same class call the plot routine?

Tags: python

So, say I have a function plot(self) within the class Pendulum that calls plot. Then I have another function plot2(self) within the same class Pendulum that also calls plot. How would I set up pyplot such that both functions would call plot on the same figure?

Answer (score 1):

In each plot function:
    figure(x)

before you call the plots, that makes the plots land on the same figure handle.

```
figure(1)
plot1(self)

figure(1)
plot2(self)
```

Edit: This works inside our outside the functions.

Comment: Uh oh - I guess I should have clarified my question better. I really meant "as different subplots within the same plot". But it's okay - I'll ask a variant of this question and upvote what you have.

Comment: That would work the same way I think, you simply call figure(x) subplot(xxx), figure(x) subplot(xxy).